# OctoberCMS backend sidemenu does not appear

Tags: octobercms

I tried to creating sub-menu in Builder Plugin, however they do not appear under Contact Us

[image: Setting backend menu using Builder Plugin]

You can see there should be two sub-menus appearing, but none of them shown.

This is the plugin.yaml

```
navigation:
    contact-us:
        label: 'stephenli.contactus::lang.plugin.name'
        url: stephenli/contactus/info
        icon: icon-life-ring
        sideMenu:
            contact-us-jumbotron:
                label: 'FAQ Top Jumbotron'
                url: stephenli/contactus/jumbotron
                icon: icon-sitemap
            contact-us-info:
                label: Information
                url: stephenli/contactus/info
                icon: icon-sitemap
```

Cannot think of why this is happening. Please request if more information is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are missing `menu context` for `controller`.

did you add this to controller

> **BackendMenu::setContext('StephenLi.ContactUs', 'contact-us');**

if **not** please add this line in `controller constructor`.

like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    BackendMenu::setContext('StephenLi.ContactUs', 'contact-us');
}
```

if still its not working please comment.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, it is working just fine. I think I would better code the backend myself instead of relying on Builder in the next project.

Comment: builder will build `controller and model` one time only so you need to `code them manually after once created`, for `menu add/update` and `form fields` you can `rely` on **builder**

Comment: So it is better to use it for starting up things then manually code afterwards

Comment: yes you can startup using builder then do your best :)